# How to hide widget in Recycler view in android based on json data in onBindHolder

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview

Hi am having a recycler view which is populated using json. I have a textview which is the category name and its repeated in the json array .I only have to show once .

```
Example :
Row 1
**My Category Name 1**
My list name 1

Row 2
My list name 2

Row 3
**My Category Name 2**
My list name 1
```

So here i need to hide **My Category Name ** based on the repeated values.
Everything worked perfect but while scrolling recyclerView its getting messed.

My Adapter Class

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewQuest.MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        final QuestModel questModel=questModelArrayList.get(position);

        String masterTitle = questModel.getSurvycat();
        if(temptitle.equalsIgnoreCase(masterTitle))
        { holder.categoryName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else
        {
            temptitle = masterTitle;
            holder.categoryName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.categoryName.setText(masterTitle);
        }

        holder.categoryName.setText(questModel.getSurvycat());
        if(questModel.getQformat().equals("Y/N")){
            holder.radioGroupQuest.setTag(questModelArrayList.get(position));
            holder.questRadio.setText(questModel.getQlist());
            holder.layoutRadio.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.layoutEditText.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }else {
            holder.questEditText.setText(questModel.getQlist());
            holder.layoutRadio.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.layoutEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }



}
```

My JSON Data

```
"messageText": [
        {
            "survycatid": 1,
            "survycat": "Category 1",
            "qsetid": 1,
            "qlistid": 1,
            "qlist": "Are you aware of this",
            "qformat": "obj"
        },
        {
            "survycatid": 1,
            "survycat": "Category 1",
            "qsetid": 1,
            "qlistid": 2,
            "qlist": "If yes, are you aware o.",
            "qformat": "Y/N"
        },
        {
            "survycatid": 1,
            "survycat": "Category 1",
            "qsetid": 1,
            "qlistid": 3,
            "qlist": "If NO, are you   aware of anyone who may be benefitted from the scheme, if included",
            "qformat": "Y/N"
        },
        {
            "survycatid": 2,
            "survycat": "Category 2",
            "qsetid": 1,
            "qlistid": 2,
            "qlist": "If yes, can you please provide the  of those to be included.",
            "qformat": "Y/N"
        },
        {
            "survycatid": 2,
            "survycat": "Category 2",
            "qsetid": 1,
            "qlistid": 5,
            "qlist": "Additional Comments",
            "qformat": "TextLine"
        },
        {
            "survycatid": 2,
            "survycat": "Category 2",
            "qsetid": 1,
            "qlistid": 1,
            "qlist": "Are you aware of the scheme",
            "qformat": "Y/N"
        },
```

I tried to hide the heading text field, its working in first try but while scrolling further its getting messed. Please get me a solution for this.

Thanks in advance. If its a small technique, then am sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: You'll have to show category then match their values with values of previous items and hide accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the support @AnshulTyagi its working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Value  for "temptitle" should not be stored as member of class. You should check if `questModelArrayList.get(position-1).getSurvycat()` is equals to `questModelArrayList.get(position).getSurvycat()`. If it is you should hide title in this ViewHolder, remeber about special case when position is 0.